# exctracting numbers with regexp

Tags: python, regex

I have some text:

```
Bounding box for object 1 "PASpersonWalking" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (160, 182) - (302, 431)
```

And I need to extract the numbers `160`, `182`, `302` and `431`.

I could come up with some splitting etc, but it seems too long. Is there a way to extract it using regexp?

Comment: So basically just use regex to extract all the numbers and then take the last four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = 'Bounding box for object 1 "PASpersonWalking" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (160, 182) - (302, 431)'
new_s = re.findall('\d+', s)[-4:]
```

Output:

```
['160', '182', '302', '431']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to extract numbers enclosing within paranthesis:

```
import re
text = 'Bounding box for object 1 "PASpersonWalking" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (160, 182) - (302, 431)'
print(re.findall(r'(\d{3,})', text))

# ['160', '182', '302', '431']
```

Comment: That regex is _very_ misleading. You should change that to `\d{3,}`. And even then it's still a questionable solution because it doesn't work for single- or double-digit numbers. I guess you meant to write `\d+, \d+`? But that would output a list of two number pairs, not 4 separate numbers.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Agreed. Updated.